# Finding Mean Value and Standard Deviation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> The distribution of resistance for resistors of a certain type is known to be normal, with 10% of all resistors having a resistance exceeding 10.256 ohms and 5% having a resistance smaller than 9.671 ohms. What are the mean value and standard deviation of the resistance distribution?

I found a solution to this problem in this link http://people.rit.edu/mjgsma/smam314winter04/exam111sol.pdf (it's the last question).

I just can't seem to make sense of what they are doing. I realize that this normal distribution is not standardizing, and that the solution uses that idea. But, as I said, I just can't seem to justify each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're given $X$ which is normal distributed with an unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown variance $\sigma^2$ which satisfies
$$
P(X>10.256)=0.1,\quad\text{and}\quad P(X<9.671)=0.05.\tag{1}
$$
Recall that if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Thus $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
P\left(Z>\frac{10.256-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.1,\quad\text{and}\quad P\left(Z<\frac{9.671-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.05,\tag{2}
$$
where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is standard normal distributed.

Now, which point satisfies that $P(Z>z)=0.1$ or equivalently $P(Z\leq z)=0.9$? This is exactly the $90\%$-percentile of the standard normal distribution which is approximately $1.28$, and hence $(2)$ becomes
$$
\frac{10.256-\mu}{\sigma}=1.28,\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{9.671-\mu}{\sigma}=?
$$
Now you have two equations with two unknowns, which you can easily solve.